# Can't install rmagick due to some gem exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am installing `rmagick` using `gem install rmagick --local` command it gives an error `gem exception unable to find spec`. Can't figure out whats wrong?

Comment: Can you add some more info? What OS are you using? What's the exact error?

Comment: Somehow resolved this issue,now getting a different error while starting the server- C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rmagick-2.12.0/lib/rmagick.
rb:11:in `require': 14001: The application has failed to start because its side-
by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or use
the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail.   - C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.
9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/extensions/x86-mingw32/1.9.1/rmagick-2.12.0/rmagick2.so
(LoadError)

Comment: Check this: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/binary-releases.php#windows Do you have Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x86) or Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x64)?

Comment: i already have imagemagick installed on my system.

Comment: And no i dont have those packages

Comment: should i download those packages?